# Google Vision API in background service?

Tags: android, preview, face-detection, google-vision

I'm trying to use the google vision api facetracker sample ( https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker )
to detect and track faces without showing the preview (at least detect, tracking is not necessary).

The main problem is that if I delete the "preview" I don't receive the callback in "onNewItem(int faceId, Face item)"  (function in FaceTrackerActivity in the github link provided).

I've been lookin through SO and I didn't find anything similar to this question, also it's not necessary that I use "google vision api", if you know another system that can achieve this objective it's perfect.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Removed the face-recognition tag, since this question is about face _tracking_ / _detection_. Face _recognition_ is a different concept, and is not supported by Google Vision AFAIK.

Comment: Missclick in the tags section, I meant "face-detection" tag, thanks Michael